# GridView within an UpdatePanel - Get Updated Textbox values on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

**IGNORE THIS:**

I was rebinding the grid in the Onload method.

I have a grid view with some textboxes, which I have to wrap in a UpdatePanel Control. So it looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDistribution" runat="server" OnLoad="upDistribution_OnLoad">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDistributions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowDataBound="gvDistributions_RowDataBound"
            CssClass="TallCells ContrastTable MaxWidth LeftHeaders"
            GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="True" style="">
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"  />

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No pricing history data found.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PriceA">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPriceA" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DistPrice">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDistPrice" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There is a button "Save" when I would like to get the value entered for the txtboxes.  If there is no UpdatePanel around the GV, i can can easily get the txtbox values like:

```
((TextBox)gvDistributions.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("txtPriceA")).Text
```

But when, the GridView is wrapped with UpdatePanel, the above statement returns the value that was set on the page load.

How can I get the value of the text box without getting rid of the updatePanel.  I need the update panel, because the number of rows, and dates are dependent on another variable in another user control.

Comment: Can you put hte button in the update panel, and use the script manager to register the button as a postback control (assuming you need the button to do a postback)?

Comment: @JamesJohnson No I cant.

Comment: Hmm... my thinking might be backwards here, but try adding `ScriptManager.GetCurrent().RegisterPostBackControl(txtDistPrice);` in the code-behind?

Comment: What are we supposed to ignore here? Did you find the answer to your question? If so, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rebinding gridview in the onLoadMethod

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you should use a trigger for the update panel which is something like below.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ...>
       <ContentTemplate>
       ...
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
       </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: How can i set the trigger from a UserControl's Textbox entry.  The Usercontrol A is on the same page as this UserControl B which holds the UpdatePanel 
If I am being confusing - 
UserControl B = usercontrol that contains the update panel
UserContorl A = user control that I want the update panel to listen to

Comment: Does the trigger go into the UpdatePanel for the GridView? My issue is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530822/how-to-access-the-textarea-value-from-a-content-page

Answer (score 0):

Use your `TextBox`es with their `AutoPostBack` property set `True`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPriceA" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```