# How to access the TextArea value from a content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, textarea, updatepanel

I have a TextArea control in my content page which is inside an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="upTaskDetailRight" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width: 98%; padding-bottom: 10px;" class="brClear">
            <div style="width: 98%; height: 120px;">
                <textarea id="taskNotes" runat="server" class="taskNotes" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-highlight-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB; scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF; scrollbar-shadow-color: #A0A0A0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #A0A0A0;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a button in my MasterPage which is accessing the TextArea value from the content page and updating the SQL Database:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel93" runat="server" CssClass="navInnerDivContentsTopSubTwo">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibSave" ImageUrl="~/theImages/Save.png" runat="server" CssClass="navImages" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="linkOff" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Code-behind:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea lblTDNotes;
lblTDNotes = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)ContentMain.FindControl("taskNotes");
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSaveQuery = @"UPDATE HSI.RMMEMO SET MEMO = '" + lblTDNotes.Value + "' WHERE MEMOID = '" + hfMemoIDYT.Value  + "'";
    //MessageBox.Show(strSaveQuery);

    using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(strMainConn))
    {
        try
        {
            scConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSaveQuery, scConn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("YourTasks.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When the page loads, the TextArea has some pre populated data. If I make any changes to the TextArea data (add or remove text) and hit the SAVE button in the Master page, the `lblTDNoted.Value` from the `strSaveQuery` is using the pre populated data and not the updated entry.

How do I get the updated entry from the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<triggers>` to your `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ...>
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: To the UpdatePanel for the textarea?

Comment: It worked the first time but the second time I added something, it didn't save it :/

Comment: When I entered a text the first time and clicked SAVE it saved correctly but when I leave the page and come back to it and make changes to the text and click SAVE, it doesn't save the update but rather keeps saving the text that I entered the first time. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Maybe you should try to change the UpdateMode to Always, instead of using triggers